# Any mocking library that works with .NET Standard 2.0?

Tags: mocking, .net-standard-2.0

as per title I'm looking for a moking library that support .net Standard 2.0.
I checked

- Moq
- FakeItEasy
- NSubstitute
- RhinoMocks

also in pre-realease.

Them are all not supported.
By not supported I mean that "using" does not find these libraries and in VS there is a warning icon on the libraries shown under References.

Suggestion?

**[Update 2018-11-23]**
FakeItEasy is OK.
Moq is OK. (tested on F# netcoreapp2.1 with Moq 4.10)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[FakeItEasy](https://github.com/FakeItEasy/FakeItEasy) contains a .NET Standard 2.0 implementation now.